# Type Username and Password using Java into a Windows Standalone application

Tags: java, windows, windows-10, cucumber

I am trying to write some Test with the use of Cucumber for a Standalone Windows application. Which requires Username and Password to Log in. I am successfully started the application and authenticated using below steps

1. ***Minimize all other applications:***

```
robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
```

2. ***Start:*** `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start " + applicationLocation);`
3. ***Bring the application to the Foreground:***

```
public class ActivateWindow {

    public interface User32 extends W32APIOptions {

        User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class, DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
        boolean ShowWindow(HWND hWnd, int nCmdShow);
        boolean SetForegroundWindow(HWND hWnd);
        HWND FindWindow(String winClass, String title);
        int SW_SHOW = 1;
    }
    public static void setForegroundWindow(String applicationName) {
        User32 user32 = User32.instance;
        HWND hWnd = user32.FindWindow(null, applicationName);
        user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, User32.SW_SHOW);
        user32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    }
}
```

4. ***Type Username and Password using the same 'Robot' used in Step-1***

```
@Given("{string} and {string}")
    public void enterUsernamePassword(String userName, String password) {
        logger.info("Username: " + userName + " Password: " + password + " are inputs");
        try {
            typeOnWindow(userName);
            ApplicationManager.getRobot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            typeOnWindow(password);
            ApplicationManager.getRobot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            ApplicationManager.getRobot().keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            ApplicationManager.getRobot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            ApplicationManager.getRobot().keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            ApplicationManager.getRobot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            ApplicationManager.getRobot().keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private void typeOnWindow(String sWord) throws InterruptedException {
        for (char c : sWord.toCharArray()) {
            ApplicationManager.getRobot().keyPress(c);
            ApplicationManager.getRobot().keyRelease(c);
            if (Settings.getBoolean("IsDemo")) {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            }
        }

    }
```

***This is my application looks like***
[image]

By this way, Test is passed very rarely. Most of the time Step-4 is not type the Username and Password in the correct location or the Input box of the application. Please provide suggestions to improve this code or Please suggest a better way to achieve this goal.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you use Robot Framework? (please remove that tag if not). I think you are using, for example: https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/robot-class/

Comment: Yes, Helio. You are right. I was not using the robot framework. It was a mistake and thanks to you to point it out.